# Use string fields as keys in type definitions

Tags: typescript

I have a Props type that looks as follows

```
type Props<FormData> = {
    formData: FormData,
    sectionNme: keyof FormData,
    name: string
}
```

but what I'd like is something akin to

```
type Props<FormData> = {
    formData: FormData,
    sectionNme: keyof FormData,
    name: keyof FormData[sectionName]
}
```

but I can't seem to access the `sectionName` field in this type definition. Is there a better way to type this, other than just `string`?

Comment: Could you give an example object how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a second type parameter:

```
type Props<FormData extends object, K extends keyof FormData = keyof FormData> = {
    formData: FormData,
    sectionNme: K,
    name: keyof FormData[K]
}
```

Usage:

```
interface MyForm {
    foo: {
        bar: string;
    }
}

const props: Props<MyForm> = {
    formData: {
        foo: {
            bar: 'hello'
        }
    },
    sectionNme: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
}
```